# Figure inside a table, problem formatting text

Tags: tables, floats, wrapfigure, wrap

I having some trouble with the text not beeing at the top inside the tabular when i add the image to the column beside it... I've tried to use wrapfigure, mixing with multirows and multicolumns and I've searched and searched both here and on the forum...

```
\begin{tabu}{|c|p{8cm}|p{5cm}|}
\hline 
 1 & Name & Comb.   \\
 & \blindtext &  \begin{figure}{[!]\includegraphics[width=5cm]{figure/final_folder_graphic.png}
 \end{figure} \\ \hline
 2 & Name & Comb.   \\
 & \blindtext & 
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{figure/final_folder_graphic.png}
 \\ \hline
```

\end{tabu}

[image: current behaviour]
[image: desired behaviour]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `figure` environment, as such a figure doesn't float. Just

```
\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{figure/final_folder_graphic.png}}
```

Answer (score 0):

See, if this can help you:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}% to show table only
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|}
\hline
text    &   text        \\
\includegraphics[valign=T,width=60mm]{example-image-4x3.pdf}
        &   \vskip-2pt
            \lipsum[2]  \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you didn't provide a MWE, I use some my old similar table. This solution work in any type of table environment. For aligning is essential `adjustbox` package.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|p{8cm}|c|}
\toprule
Sno & Name & Comb.   \\
\midrule
1& \vspace{-4.5cm}{ \lipsum[1] }&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{albt.png}}\\ 
\midrule
2& \vspace{-4.5cm}{ \lipsum[1] }&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{ \includegraphics[width=5cm]{albt.png}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

When use booktabs vertical lines are not used. However, for display purpose I have used.

[image: display]